# In search for the domain in which the inequality holds

Tags: calculus, inequality

I wrote this simple inequality and raised the question what is the maximal domain such that the inequality holds, and the inequality is:

$\dfrac{1}{x+y}>{\dfrac{1}{x}}+{\dfrac{1}{y}}$. ($x,y\neq0$,$x+y\neq0$)

Now I naturally asked myself what is the maximal subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^2$ such that the inequality holds on $S$? It is straightforward to show that if $x,y>0$ then the inequality doesn`t holds, and also that if $x,y<0$ then the inequality holds. The real problem lies in the parts of the plane where $x>0,y<0$ or $x<0,y>0$ beacuse in that regions for some values the inequality holds and for some it doesn´t holds, here are some examples:

$x=-1/4,y=2/4 \implies 4>-2$, so it holds for these values

$x=-4,y=1 \implies 1/(-3)<3/4$, so it doesn´t holds for these values

$x=(-9)/10,y=8/10 \implies -10<5/36$, so it doesn`t holds for these values

So I am really trying to find necessary and sufficient conditions on $x$ and $y$ such that the inequality holds. Does anyone see an efficient way to solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume wlog $x>0>y$. Then your inequality is equivalent to

$$\frac{xy}{x+y}<x+y$$

Now if $x+y>0$ the left hand side will be negative and the right hand side positive, so the inequality is true.
If $x+y<0$ the inequality is equivalent to

$$-xy>x^2+y^2$$ which can't be true. Thus the answer is:

$x,y<0$, or $x>|y|>0$, or $y>|x|>0$.

Comment: Actually, it is equivalent to $x+y<{\dfrac {xy}{x+y}}$, does it change the final conclusion?

Comment: I multiplied both sides with $xy$ which is negative.

Comment: $\dfrac {1}{x+y}> {\dfrac {1}{x}}+{\dfrac {1}{y}} \implies \dfrac {1}{x+y}>\dfrac {x+y}{xy} \implies x+y<\dfrac {xy}{x+y}$. You need to turn it other way, but the conclusion could be the same.

Comment: The rule you are using only holds if both sides have the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$x+y \ge 2(xy)^{\dfrac{1}{2}}$$

$x,y \ge0$

Inequality changes when reciprocate
$$\dfrac{1}{x+y} \le \frac{1}{(2x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Similarly, find the maximum value of $\dfrac{1}{x}+ \dfrac{1}{y}$

Comment: I am not sure if that will work, your inequality doesn`t work when $x<0,y>0$ or when $x>0,y<0$ because then the square root is non-existent, or am I missing something?

Comment: **AM-GM** works for Positive reals.

Comment: I don`t need it for positive reals since I have shown that this inequality doesn´t holds when $x,y>0$, and it is also written in explanation of the problem.